# How much memory should be assigned to Java on Tomcat, using Solr with 20+ M items in the index?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, solr, tomcat7

I'm looking for some advice on memory allocation to Java on Tomcat 7, running Solr :-)

Here are the facts:

- Running **Solr 1.4.1** with approx **20 Million items** of different sizes in the index.
- The index, when trimmed, is approx **40-45 GB** large.
- Approx **40000-60000 articles** are added to the index every **month**. Articles vary in size, from a couple of kBs to 15-20 kBs.
- Approx **5000-8000 images** are added to the index every **month**. (Actually not the images themselves but some meta data).

Solr config specifics:

- mergeFactor 10
- ramBufferSizeMB 128 MB
- maxMergeMB 1024.0 MB

When doing a full re-index (on a Win 2007 server with Intel Xeon CPU (4 cores) + 6 GB memory), indexing diary entries takes approx 3,5 hrs and indexing images takes approx 4,5 hrs.

However, we've upgraded the **index server to 12 GB memory** and assigned Java **6144 MB for the maximum memory pool**. **Initial memory pool: 1024 MB**.

When restarting Apache, it takes approx 5-10 minutes for Tomcat to reach ~ 5 GB of memory usage. Another hour or two and it hits the 6 GB barrier and stays there.

When we had a 2 GB barrier using 32 bit Apache, we got an OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space after 1-1,5 weeks. 3 GB added up to maybe 2-3 weeks.

Right now we've run Solr on 64 bit Apache and Java with 6 GB assigned for a couple of days. So far no problems.

Given above facts, what would you do to trim the Solr index and tweak memory usage?

Comment: have you seen http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors#RAM_Usage_Considerations ?

Answer (score 1):

How big is you image index? Have you considered seperating the two indexes? If you put them onto seperate SOLR instances on seperate boxes you should see a performance increase.

Comment: Right now we have a it of a constraint using more servers than one. That will probably change in the future.

Image index is approx 20 GB. Haven't separated the indexes just yet!

Comment: You can also shard across seperate services on the same server.  Put one on port 8983 and the next on 8984!